# Excel search for string in multiple cells, compare and display string with most counts

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Excel 2013

I have a table as follow:

```
    A
1   CHI
2   SEA
3   SEA
4   LA
...
```

How do I write a formula that can check cells A1 ~ A4 and display on another cell the string with most count? In this example, B1 displays `SEA` has the most count.

```
    B
1   SEA
```

To simplify this task, let's say `CHI`, `SEA`, `LA` are pre-determined entries. I could use a table to keep the counts:

```
    M    N
1   CHI  1
2   SEA  2
3   LA   1
```

But I would need help on writing formula for N1 ~ N3 to populate the count.

A variant of this question can be found here:
[Excel search for substring and display count](https://superuser.com/questions/1080069/excel-search-for-substring-and-display-count)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the count in N1 put:

```
=COUNTIF($A:$A,M1)
```

then you can use this formula to find the value with the most:

```
=INDEX(M:M,MATCH(MAX(N:N),N:N,0))
```

[image]

---

To return the value that is repeated the most with one formula, use this array formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$4,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$4,$A$1:$A$4)),COUNTIF($A$1:$A$4,$A$1:$A$4),0))
```

Being an array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  If done properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

With array formulas we want to reference only the ranges with data, and not use full column references.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Holy macro. Glad I asked, could never figure this out by myself. Thanks I will try it.

Comment: Scott, I have an extended question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/1080069/excel-search-for-substring-and-display-count), can you help follow it up? I do not want to modify this post as your answer can help others.