# Excel search for substring and display count

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is an extended question from [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1079998/excel-search-for-string-in-multiple-cells-compare-and-display-string-with-most).

Suppose now I have a following table with strings:

```
    A
1   CHI111
2   SEA222
3   SEA333
4   LA444
...
```

I also plan to have a table to keep count of keywords `CHI`, `SEA`, and `LA`:

```
    M    N
1   CHI  1
2   SEA  2
3   LA   1
```

How do I write formula for N1 ~ N3 to populate count?

**Edit**: Adding a slight variant

Now the table has two keywords with same number of entries:

```
    A
1   CHI111
2   SEA222
3   SEA333
4   LA444
5   LA555
...
```

How do I display in a cell with two keywords separated by a separator (comma, slash, &). Like so:

```
    M    N   O
1   CHI  1   SEA, LA
2   SEA  2
3   LA   2
```

Additionally, if counts for all three keywords are the same, it will need to be displayed as "ALL"

```
    M    N   O
1   CHI  2   ALL
2   SEA  2
3   LA   2
```

THANKS FOR HELP!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the count in N1 put:

```
=COUNTIF($A:$A,"*" & M1 & "*")
```

then you can use this formula to find the value with the most:

```
=INDEX(M:M,MATCH(MAX(N:N),N:N,0))
```

[image]

---

In one formula, with your prefixes still in M1:M3, use this array formula:

```
=INDEX($M$1:$M$3,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$4,"*"&$M$1:$M$3&"*")),COUNTIF($A$1:$A$4,"*"&$M$1:$M$3&"*"),0))
```

Being an array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  If done properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

With array formulas we want to reference only the ranges with data, and not use full column references.

[image]

Comment: Scott, thanks for fast response. I don't know how to give you more credit than you already deserve! I added another variant in the post, can you help?

Comment: That is a new question and makes this answer irrelevant and exposes me to down votes. The changes you ask for are not possible unless you are using the latest office 365 or using vba.

Comment: @Howard You can give Scott credit by marking his answer as "Answered" with a check mark if he answered your question